# Passing arguments to objective function fmincon Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to minimize an objective function which consists of variables other than the constraint variable. Is there a way to pass arguments to such a function, for example:

```
data = xlsread('Returns.xlsx', 'Sheet2','A2:F324');

for i = 1:10
    returns = data(i:i+59,1:5);
    fund = data(i:i+59,6:6);
    lb = [0;0;0;0;0];
    ub = [1; 1; 1; 1; 1];
    [betas, fval] = fmincon(@obj_function, [0 .2 .2 .2 .2 .2], [], [], [], [], lb, ub, @constraints);
end
```

And the objective function is defined as:

```
function [ value ] = obj_function(betas)
    value = returns*betas(2:6) + betas(1);
    value = sum((value - fund)^2);
end
```

Since my objective function needs to extra variables `returns` and `fund`, what is the best way I can keep passing it from the main function? Below statement is invalid, what else can I do?

`[betas, fval] = fmincon(@obj_function(returns, fund), [.2 .2 .2 .2 .2], [], [], [], [], lb, ub, @constraints);`

EXTRA, function constraint is defined as follows:

```
function [ c, ceq ] = constraints( betas )
    c = [];
    ceq = betas(2)*1 + betas(3)*1 + betas(4)*1 + betas(5)*1 + betas(6)*1 - 1;
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use anonymous functions to create [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29):

```
a = 1; b = 2;
[...] = fmincon(@(x) myObjFcn(x, a, b), ...)
```

Here is a documentation page explaining this in more details:

> [Passing Extra Parameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html)

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use `global returns fund`